# How do I add a custom css style to Sharepoint modern?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm creating an Intranet for my company, and I'm trying to style the Sharepoint template to match the company colors. I've been looking endlessly for how to add css to Sharepoint, but the closest answers I gotten are outdated or are beyond convoluted. Surely there's a relatively easy and straightforward way to add css to a Sharepoint site?

Tried uploading a css file to the Assets folder

Comment: Hi, according to your description and the ta you added, I think you are using SharePoint Online. And for Online, the answer below is very good, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave no indication on the version of the SharePoint environment you're using, I will be supposing the following: SharePoint Online, modern experience.

Customizing the modern experience is indeed very limited. The only official support is creating a custom theme (main color, text color, background color) and applying it to the sites you want.

To go beyond in the simplest way, and for example, loading a CSS file, you will need a SharePoint Framework solution to load the CSS file into the page, as it is not officially or natively supported by Microsoft.

Such a solution is actually quite simple, with a SPFx solution with a single Application Customizer that adds a link to you stylesheet on the site on every page.

A quick google search gave me this project with this kind of approach: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/main/samples/react-application-injectcss/README.md

The downside however, is that your code (and thus your stylesheet) will not be immediately loaded at the page load, as it is loaded after the page load, resulting in a potential visual glitch (<0.5s normally) if your modification are important (such as changing the font or the layout of the page).

If to you looks is everything, I would suggest dropping the modern experience and going back to the classic experience, where you have a master page (.aspx) where you can add all the css you want. But doing so would change the whole experience on your site and should be pondered appropriately.